# Listing in Amazon Marketplace using ASINs

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I have a list of ASINs and I want to list them into amazon market place using MWS. I think that I need some xml data. please help me in doing so.

I also want to add my mrp (price) to those products within xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the [Feeds API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?group=bde&section=feeds) to send products to Amazon through MWS.  Please read the documentation.